# Safari Web Inspector network throttling

Tags: debugging, safari, remote-debugging, web-inspector

I'm currently remote-debugging a website on my iPhone using Safari v8 and need to simulate different network speeds.

The Chrome Developer Tools have the functionality to throttle the network connection (simulate 3G, wifi etc.) or even to completely switch it off.

Does the Safari Web Inspector have similar functionality?

At the moment I'm getting around it by just switching off my wifi as I just need to test no network for now, but might need the functionality in the future.

Comment: I tried using this library to enable Chrome dev tool debugging for iOS devices https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy. Everything works...except for the network throttling.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is currently not a way to do that natively in Safari but you might try using something like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) that can throttle your browser or system connection (win, mac, linux).

[image: Mac version of Charles proxy throttle settings]

Answer (score 17):

As of safari Version 16.6 In dev tools settings under the Experimental tab there is a checkbox "Allow throttling" in the Network section.
[image]
Once you've reloaded the dev tools there will be a dropdown to the right of "Disable Caches" where you can select the network throttle.
[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is 100% correct.

Comment: Weirdly there's no option to 100% throttle, which is the one I need most for dev purposes.

Comment: anyone know how to make this behave like chrome, where every single request is throttled? it seems do some caching or something that doesn't make it a genuine throttle

Answer (score 10):

**Update for 2023 and later**

Other answers are no longer up to date and don't work anymore. Today you need to use an add-on from Apple called **Network Link Conditioner**.

You can download it with [additional tools for xCode](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=additional%20tools%20for%20xcode).

[image: Network Link Conditioner by]

Answer (score 7):

Just found a way to do it without having to use a proxy like Charles:

1. Install XCode
2. Connect iPhone to mac via USB
3. Launch XCode
4. Access developer settings on iPhone
5. Use "Network Link Conditioner"

Longer blog post I wrote: [Enable network throttling on iPhone in 5 steps](https://dev.to/vvo/enable-network-throttling-on-iphone-applications-in-5-steps-ikf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no Network setting to be found anymore on the latest xCode :(