# Angular load time is too long (too slow) on Safari (both Mac and iOS), much longer than Chrome (PC and Android)

Tags: angular, performance, safari

Angular app loading is too slow on Safari, it takes much more time than it's on Chrome.
Both on PC and mobile device.
A same app,
Chrome:  9.47s
Safari: 27.78s

And on the Safari, there has some time no any action.
How to increase its load performance on Safari?
Appreciate any advice!

--Anndy

[image: angular app load on Chrome]
[image: angular app load on Safari]

Comment: becase your speed is throttled in safari, if you notice closely each file is taking more time to download in your safari as compared to chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Your network speed is throttled in safari for some reason. Because each bundle is taking atleast 4 times the time to download that in chrome. It's not angular's performance issue. It might be some configuration in your safari.

One of the references i could find is :- [Safari Web Inspector network throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669674/safari-web-inspector-network-throttling)